# Mechanics, trying to find the absolute velocity of a bead on a tube

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A rectilinear tube of length 2l rotates with a constant angular speed ω around the vertical axis through the middle of the tube at a constant angle αα!=0 with the tube. The tube does not move up or down. A bead slides along the tube.

At some moment of time the bead is at a distance bb from the middle of the tube, and has a speed Vr relative to the tube. What is the absolute speed Va of the bead at this moment of time?

I know you need to use pythagoras. SO far I calculated the transport velocity as ωb and just left the relative velocity as Vr as I can't work out any other answer it could be. So then is the absolute velocity just the square root of
(ω^2)(b^2) + (Vr)^2
?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690282/mechanics-question-concerning-rotating-tube

Comment: which is itself a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690282/265466 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693189/265466.